# How to register alac decoder to multimedia framework?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, stagefright

Inside mp4 extractor we added support to parse ALAC encoded frames.
Added SoftOMXComponent for ALAC decoder

Following files we modified for decoder MIME type registration:

1. OMXUtils.cpp inside function GetComponentRole() added below code: `static const MimeToRole kMimeToRole[] = { { "audio/alac","audio_decoder.alac", "audio_encoder.alac" },}`
2. In SoftOMXPlugin.cpp added
   `{ "OMX.google.alac.decoder", "allgoalacdec", "audio_decoder.alac" }` to kComponents[]
3. In media_codecs_google_audio.xml Added an entry for ALAC as below:
4. Inside media/libstagefright/Utils.cpp
   Added an entry for ALAC at

   static const struct mime_conv_t mimeLookup[] = {
       { "audio/alac", AUDIO_FORMAT_ALAC},
   }

5.Inside /libstagefright/ACodec.cpp at: status_t ACodec::configureCodec()
Added for ALAC

```
else if (!strcasecmp(mime, "audio/alac")) {
    int32_t numChannels;
    int32_t sampleRate;
    if (!msg->findInt32("channel-count", &numChannels)
            || !msg->findInt32("sample-rate", &sampleRate)) {
        /* We do not want to setup the ALAC codec.Let the
         * Plugin do all the work*/
        err = OK;
    } else {
        err = setupRawAudioFormat(
                kPortIndexOutput,
                sampleRate,
                numChannels);
        err = OK;
    }
}
```

And Inside status_t:

```
ACodec::getPortFormat(){

    case OMX_AUDIO_CodingALAC:
        {
            OMX_AUDIO_PARAM_ALACTYPE params;

            InitOMXParams(&params);

            params.nPortIndex = portIndex;


            err = mOMXNode->getParameter(

                    (OMX_INDEXTYPE)OMX_IndexParamAudioAlac, &params, sizeof(params));

            if (err != OK) {

                return err;

            }

            notify->setString("mime", "audio/alac");

            notify->setInt32("channel-count", params.nChannels);

            notify->setInt32("sample-rate", params.nSamplingRate);

            // notify->setInt32("bits-per-sample", params.nBitsPerSample);

            break;

        }
}
```

We added above changes and build libstagefright and copied to board also media_codecs_google_audio.xml copied to hardware's /vendor/etc

But still we getting below error:

> NuPlayerDecoder: Failed to create audio/alac decoder